# keep the branch name in source code

Tags: git, merge, branch

I want to have the branch name of git repo, somewhere in my (Python) codes
I want to decide many things in my code based on branch name, even if `.git` directory is not present (in case the program is running by user, who has downloaded a source archive with no `.git` directory)

But when I set the branch name to a variable in my code, I have to constantly fix that variable after every cross-branch merging, which is a pain.

I wonder if there is an easier and safer way to do that.
I've heard of git hooks, But I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

Comment: I still have this question after 6 years. The only solution that comes to my mind is still with git hooks (on multiple git commands like `branch`, `checkout`, `merge`, and specially `rebase`) that is very troublesome (specially an script for defining hooks on every new dev machine)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use branch name as some kind of metadata, consider using git
 notes.

this link might help on notes; https://speakerdeck.com/matthewmccullough/git-notes-and-github

Comment: Notes are saved in `.git` directory. How am I supposed to get access to it in my source code when `.git` might not exist?

Comment: I think I have to register an event to save the branch name somewhere outside of `.git` and that event should be run before every merge commit (or normal commit), or after every checkout.